# Python detect_event() just works in IDE

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a script for my raspberry PI and standing in front of a problem.

I like to interpret the edges of several GPIO-Inputs. Therefor, I'm using the python functions `GPIO.event_detected` and `GPIO.add_event_detect`. 
This works fine in the IDE, but if I try to use the script with the Shell `sudo python3 script.py` nothing happens when I press the Buttons.

I'm initializing the GPIOs with:

```
numbtns = len(buttons)
index = 0

for index in range(numbtns):
    GPIO.setup(buttons[index], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(buttons[index],GPIO.RISING,bouncetime=200)`
```

And check the buttons with:

```
if(GPIO.event_detected(GPIO_RADIO)):
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work in the shell?

Edit: here is a compilation of interesting code snippets out of my script

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
from threading import Thread


#GPIO-Belegung
GPIO_RADIO      = 18
GPIO_PREV       = 11
GPIO_NEXT       = 9
GPIO_DOWN       = 17
GPIO_UP         = 15
GPIO_SELECT     = 14
GPIO_MUSIK      = 16 
GPIO_TEMPERATUR = 4

# GPIO Konfig
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


buttons         =[GPIO_RADIO,GPIO_PREV,GPIO_NEXT,GPIO_TEMPERATUR,GPIO_DOWN,GPIO_UP,GPIO_SELECT]

def init_gpio(buttons):
    numbtns = len(buttons)

    index = 0

    for index in range(numbtns):
        GPIO.setup(buttons[index], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(buttons[index],GPIO.RISING,bouncetime=200)

def main():
    ...
    init_gpio(buttons)
    ...
    while True:
        if(GPIO.event_detected(GPIO_RADIO)):
            do something...
        ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How are you running this in an IDE? on the RPi?  You get no results? no error messages?

Comment: Exactly the Script runs in the build im IDE(python 3, Raspian Image) without ans errors or warnings.

Comment: can you run a simpler script from the shell to see if that works as a first step?

Comment: A simple Script with event_detected or in general? If i take the same Script and replace "event_detected" with "input", the Script is Working.

Comment: do you need to import GPIO? Your questions shows two blocks of identical code.  If you can show the entire script it might show something you have overlooked

Comment: Yes,GPIO is imported in this script. The hole Script ist about 250-300 rows of code. Is it ok to post it?

Comment: Why is the code to check buttons the same as the code to initialize GPO?

Comment: also, tag this question with raspberry pi tags, you might get a bigger audience

Comment: Thanks vor your answers. This was a classic copy-paste fail. I update the question at evening. Oh man....

Comment: so, copy and paste the complete python file to your question

Comment: thanks for the answers! i´ve updatet the question above and took the relevant code from my script in.

Comment: I looked at your code.  I have a Pi, but no breadboard to test.  Your code looks good.  I would check the gpio connections.  I'm also wondering what is the IDE you used that gave you good results? Is it running on the Pi?

Comment: Im not shure if its good enove to call it ide. I use the Python 3 application in Raspian in the UI. Thats a simple text Editor with interpreter, to be found under Development on desktop

Comment: wow... now i`m a step closer to the solution ... What i found out is: the GPIO.event_detected works until i use a function of the "os"-class. if i use os.popen() or os.system in my script GPIO.event_detected stops working.  What the f.... ? any ideas?